# Discord Bot can't play audio from YouTube all of a sudden

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, youtube, bots

Last night my Discord bot stopped working out of the blue. The bot had been working perfectly for months until this point - no code changes occurred and it was running in a Docker container on my home server. Then last night, my `!play <URL>` command stopped working. The bot would join the voice channel, but not actually play anything. Then it would need to be manually disconnected from the voice channel in order for it to do anything again. After the first play fails, and I try again I get this error message:

```bash
 [youtube] crOZk88eCcg: Downloading webpage
 [youtube] crOZk88eCcg: Downloading android player API JSON
 [youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crOZk88eCcg&ab_channel=0foofighter0
 [youtube] crOZk88eCcg: Downloading webpage
 [youtube] crOZk88eCcg: Downloading android player API JSON
 [2023-03-22 00:27:59] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command play
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 190, in wrapped
     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/src/app/./main.py", line 180, in play
     voice.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 600, in play
     raise ClientException('Not connected to voice.')
 discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.
 
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 199, in wrapped
     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
 discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.
 [2023-03-22 00:27:59] [INFO    ] discord.player: ffmpeg process 12 has not terminated. Waiting to terminate...
 [2023-03-22 00:27:59] [INFO    ] discord.player: ffmpeg process 12 should have terminated with a return code of -9.
```

My first instinct was that ffmpeg was borking somehow, since it has been difficult to get working in the past. However I'm not sure how ffmpeg could've stopped working, since the bot never went down between working and not working. That leads me to believe it could be a change on Youtube/Discord's side?

For context, here is a snippet of my `!play` code:

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx):
    url = ctx.message.content.split("!play ",1)[1]
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients)
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        if voice == None:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            voice = await channel.connect()

        # Youtube Magic
        ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'worstaudio/worst',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        }

        if "http" not in url:
            yt = YoutubeSearch(url, max_results=1).to_json()
            print(yt)
            yt_id = str(json.loads(yt)['videos'][0]['id'])
            yt_channel = str(json.loads(yt)['videos'][0]['channel']).strip().replace(" ", "")
            url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+yt_id+"&ab_channel="+yt_channel

        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            song_info=ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        for file in os.listdir("./"):
            if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

        voice.stop()

        embed_trk = discord.Embed(
                title="Now playing",
                color=ctx.author.color,
        )
        video_title = song_info.get('title', None)
        video_channel = song_info.get('uploader', None)
        embed_trk.add_field(name="Track title", value=video_title, inline=False)
        embed_trk.add_field(name="Channel", value=video_channel, inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed_trk)
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop, stream=True)
        voice.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)
        while voice.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
        await request_record(ctx, video_title)

    else:
        await ctx.send("You must be in a voice channel to run this command")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I had my `discord.py` version locked to an older release. Unlocking it and rebuilding the Docker container lets the bot play music.